Solve min-max optimization problem over probabilities
I want to solve the optimization problem, given $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n>0$,
\begin{align*}
&\min_{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\in\mathbb{R}}\max_{i\in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}}\frac{a_i}{p_i} \\
&p_1,p_2, \ldots, p_n>0 \\
&p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_n=1.
\end{align*}
Now, I need to show that the solution is given by $p_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_ja_j}$. Now, if I plug this in, I get that the minimum value is given by $\sum_j a_j$, so I would essentially need to prove that
$$\max_{i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}}\frac{a_i}{p_i}\geq\sum_{j=1}^na_j$$
for any probability distribution $p_i$. The only issue is the "max" function is not a nice function to work with algebraically, so I am a bit stuck. Does anyone have a hint on how to start?

Denote $L = \max_{i\in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}}\frac{a_i}{p_i}$, then
$$\begin{align}
&L\ge \frac{a_i}{p_i}  \hspace{1cm} i=1,...,n\\
\implies & p_i\ge  \frac{a_i}{L}  \hspace{1cm} i=1,...,n \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Take the sum of $n$ inequalities $(1)$, we deduce then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \ge \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i }{L}$$
that is
$$L\ge \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \tag{2}$$
The equality of $(2)$ occurs if and only if all equalities of $(1)$ occur, i.e. $p_i = \frac{a_i}{L_{\min}} =  \frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$ for all $i=1,...,n$.
Q.E.D

Proof by contradiction. Assume the above inequality does not hold, which means for all $j$ we have
$$\frac{a_j}{p_j} <\sum_{i=1}^na_i .$$
Hence,
$$a_j < (\sum_{i=1}^na_i) ~p_j$$.
Now take the sum over j indices. Done

One way would be to see that for any $f_1,...,f_n\in ℝ$ we have that $$\max_{k\in\left[n\right]}{f_k}=\max_{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in\left[0,1\right]\atop\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\alpha_if_i}}$$
